# RavenDb extremely slow inserts at around 2KB per seconds

Tags: ravendb

Testing out RavenDb on a standard i7 4790K machine with 24GB Ram and a 512GB NVME SSD.

Using the very basic bulk insert from [RavenDB Bulk Inserts] https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/client-api/bulk-insert/how-to-work-with-bulk-insert-operation , I'm getting extremely slow write speeds with documents being inserted at around 10 per seconds.

```
using (BulkInsertOperation bulkInsert = store.BulkInsert())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000; i++)
    {
        bulkInsert.Store(new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName #" + i,
            LastName = "LastName #" + i
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot from dashboard]
This seems ridiculously slow and makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong. The test app is a simple .net core 3.1 console application. I have tried the standard insert as well and the results aren't any different.

The server is running on the same laptop with default install settings and is not setup for a secure connection at the moment.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind - during the bulk insert, I'd check "disk queue length"  to see if some other process is saturating the disk's IO. Another thing to try is monitor individual file writes using Sysinternals Procmon in Windows or utils like iotop or strace if you use Linux - that would prove/disprove whether the disk is a bottleneck